# Is it possible to use tf.keras.models.clone_model to change shape of data input?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I'd like to use the method `clone_model` of `tf.keras` and change the input shape of a tensorflow/keras model created by the functional API. Therefore, I try to use the argument `input_tensor` to change the shape. However, it does not seem to use the provided `input_tensors` and the name and the shape stays the same as the original model. What is the argument `input_tensors` intended to be used for?

The code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers

inputs_small = layers.Input((64, 64, 3), name="small")

outputs = layers.Conv2D(32, 1)(inputs_small)
model_small = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs_small, outputs=outputs)


inputs_large = layers.Input((128, 128, 3), name="large")
model_large = tf.keras.models.clone_model(model_small, input_tensors=inputs_large)

model_large.summary()
```

results in:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
small (InputLayer)           [(None, 64, 64, 3)]       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 64, 64, 32)        128       
=================================================================
```

but I like to have:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
large (InputLayer)           [(None, 128, 128, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 128, 128, 32)      128       
=================================================================
```

I use TensorFlow 2.4.1. and I simplified my problem. In my code, I also use the argument `clone_function` of `clone_model` to replace layers.

Comment: If your sole purpose is to resize the image., consider adding a [`Resizing`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Resizing) layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I investigated further and found a Keras bug:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/14937